# Is prostatitis a STD or Contagious disease?

Tags: prostatitis

As prostatitis is a disease in male's prostate gland, does it mean this is a sexually transmitted disease?

Comment: What research have you now done to answer this question?

Comment: No, it does not. Prostatitis will not be transmitted to any one by any way. Patients can have sex with other people even they are suffering from chronic prostatitis.

Comment: The usual practice is to wait a few days, and if this question is not answered you can then choose to answer yourself with references.

Comment: @GrahamChiu I‘m not aware of that practice. Some people ask and answer simultaneously (the system even allows that). I‘d suggest posting an answer as soon as OP finds one.

Comment: I recall when you post you aren't allowed to answer for two days

Comment: @GrahamChiu you can answer instantly, you can't accept your own answer though until 48 hours passed. (To give chance for others)

Answer (score 11):

[Prostatitis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostatitis) isn't an STD, or a contagious disease, or even a disease at all.  The term "prostatitis" simply refers to [inflammation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflammation) of the prostate gland.  The underlying condition causing the inflammation could be any of a number of things, which, yes, include contagious and sexually-transmitted diseases.

Answer (score 0):

Prostatitis is a common disease in men. It's neither a STD nor a contagious disease. *[Prostatitis](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/prostatitis/symptoms-causes/syc-20355766)* often causes painful or difficult urination. Other symptoms include pain in the groin, pelvic area or genitals and sometimes flu-like symptoms.

Prostatitis treatments depend on the underlying cause.Like antibiotics or a diuretic and anti-inflammatory pill. Bedides, there are some home remedies, like have a warm sitz bath, 
and avoid activities that can irritate your prostate, such as prolonged sitting or bicycling.